# How can I reduce the download time of a Javascript fetch request?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am having trouble with long fetch requests that slow down my code. I am trying to build a google chrome extension that works on top of [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com) and includes fetch requests to other amazon product pages (after scraping them from the DOM model of the current page). My code works, but it is slow, with each requets taking 2.5-3 seconds, and the sum of requets often taking up to 10. [Here is the Network Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXDmd.png). As seen in the network request, a vast majority of this time is download for the fetch, which takes ~2 seconds, even though the html to be downloaded is not all that large. Are there any good ways to speed this process up?

I have tried looking into whether I could compress the files from my fetch command, but this was already done automatically by Amazon and did not improve my speed. I have also tried seeing if I could find a way to only get a selective portion of the html I'm trying to fetch, but haven't had any success.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Depends on what you are doing. You can cache the first request if you only need to request certain data once. Might not be possible. What is the source code to reproduce?

Comment: If your page performs several tasks, log the timing of each task to better focus your improvements   If some async tasks can be done in parallel, then that's an easy way to make quick gains.

Comment: `a vast majority of this time is download for the fetch` - you say the content is small - you say it, but there's no indication of the content size, so, we have only your word. Assuming it is only small, then only two things I can think of that make it slow. 1 - bandwidth between you and the server is slow; or 2 - the server is sending the data slowly. Neither of which you can do anything about

Answer (score -1):

Instead of making individual fetch requests for each Amazon product page, consider batching multiple requests together. Group similar requests and send them in a single fetch call, which can significantly reduce the overhead associated with multiple HTTP requests.

Comment: Can you kindly explain _"consider batching multiple requests together"_? Is the reduction headers only get sent and received once?

Comment: How does one "group" requests to different URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by *"similar requests"*?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).